# How to save a text file from the browser?

Tags: browser, files, downloading

I was reading a game FAQ on my Galaxy S II with the stock browser, and was a little surprised that I had no option to save the `.txt` file to the phone.

Is this possible?

Comment: If the FAQ has a link to "View/Download Original File", long-press on it and "Save link".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Dolphin Browser HD](https://market.android.com/details?id=mobi.mgeek.TunnyBrowser) has the ability to save the current site that you are viewing:

```
More -> Save Site
```

Comment: The question does not ask how to save the current site from Dolphin, but how to save a link to a file in general. In most Android browsers you only need to long press on a link and choose 'save link'